# Calculo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Tenho dois campos numéricos em meu sistema como mostra a foto abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo que esta com uma linha vermelha em volta, ele terá que fazer um calculo sobre o campo de cima, como podem ver no campo **Creatinina...** esta com um valor de 2.3, o campo em vermelho só aceitara aquele valor de 2.3 + 0.3 no caso seria 2.6 pra cima.

Resumindo, o campo em vermelho aceitara somente os valores do campo de cima mais 0.3, como exemplo seria 2.6 pra mais, não poderia aceitar valores abaixo disso

irei postar meu código que tentei fazer aqui:

```js
function formulaCreabas2() {
        var valueCreabas2 = $('[name="creabas2"]').val();
        var valueCrebas = $('[name="creabas"]').val();
    
        var subCreab = valueCrebas - valueCreabas2
        console.log(subCreab);
        if (subCreab < 0.2999999999999997) {
            $('#creabas2-msg').removeClass('display-none');
            $('#creabas2-msg').text('Não há como comprovar a informação. Dúvidas: entre em contato com a equipe do estudo.');
            $('[name = "creabas2"]').val('');
        } else {
            $('#creabas2-msg').addClass('display-none');
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group topo">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>
                                            Creatinina (posterior à admissão hospitalar e a mais próxima da randomização): <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 target">
                                        <div style="width: 180px;" class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="00.00" value="creabas" name="creabas" min="0" max="15" />
                                            <div style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">mg/dL</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label id="creabas-error" class="input-error" for="creabas" style="border: none; color: red;"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<div class="row" id="creba2nd">
                                <div class="form-group topo">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>
                                            Se necessário, informe mais uma medida da creatinina nas 48 horas prévias a randomização, que comprove a elevação de 0,3mg/dL ou incremento de 50% no valor basal: <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 exibeEsconde">
                                        <div style="width: 180px;" class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="00.00" value="creabas2" name="creabas2" min="0" max="15" />
                                            <div style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">mg/dl</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label id="creabas2-error" class="input-error" for="creabas2" style="border: none; color: red;"></label>
                                        <label id="creabas2-msg" class="text-danger display-none" for="creabas2"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**creabas** é a variável do primeiro campo, **Creatinina...**

**creabas2** é a variável do campo **Se necessário...**

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML para testarmos?

Comment: só um momento que vou criar aqui

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w8p14wx3/

Comment: Leonardo, pode me tirar algumas dúvidas em relação sua pergunta? 1- Em que momento deve ocorrer o calculo de possíveis valores, ou seja, quando deve ser chamado a função formulaCreabas2(). 2- A ideia é que o valor do segundo input seja sempre superior ao valor do primeiro + 0.3, ou seja, quaisquer valores superior ou igual a X+0.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function formulaCreabas2() {
    var valueCreabas2 = parseFloat($('[name="creabas2"]').val());
    var valueCrebas = parseFloat($('[name="creabas"]').val()) + 0.3;

    if (valueCreabas2 < valueCrebas) {
        $('#creabas2-msg').removeClass('display-none');
        $('#creabas2-msg').text('Não há como comprovar a informação. Dúvidas: entre em contato com a equipe do estudo.');
        $('[name = "creabas2"]').val('');
    } else {
        $('#creabas2-msg').addClass('display-none');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu script está correto, talvez tenha faltado o `parseFloat` pois a função `.val()` retorna uma `string`, eu refatorei o seu código.

```js
//função para calcular a diferença
function formulaCreabas(valorCreabas2, valorCreabas, sucesso, erro) {
    var valorCreabas = parseFloat(valorCreabas);
    var valorCreabas2 = parseFloat(valorCreabas2);
    

    var subCreab = valorCreabas - valorCreabas2
    console.log(subCreab);
    if (subCreab < 0.2999999999999997) {
        if(erro) erro();
    } else {
        if(sucesso) sucesso();
    } 
}

//função de callback caso a diferença esteja ok
function sucessoCreabas() {
  console.info("Cálculo de Creabas ok.");
  //$('#creabas2-msg').addClass('display-none');
}

//função de callback caso a diferença seja menor que 0.3
function erroCreabas() {
  console.error("Não há como comprovar a informação. Dúvidas: entre em contato com a equipe do estudo.");
  //$('#creabas2-msg').removeClass('display-none');
  //$('#creabas2-msg').text('Não há como comprovar a informação. Dúvidas: entre em contato com a equipe do estudo.');
  //$('[name = "creabas2"]').val('');  
}


formulaCreabas(2.3, 2.6, sucessoCreabas, erroCreabas);
formulaCreabas(2.5, 2.6, sucessoCreabas, erroCreabas);

//o que você precisa chamar
//formulaCreabas($('[name="creabas2"]').val(), $('[name="creabas"]').val(), sucessoCreabas, erroCreabas);
```

Comment: consegui resolver aqui vou postar

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente as propriedades `min` e `max` do seu `input` não vão funcionar, pois não se aplicam ao `type="text"`, então mudei para o `type="number"` e adicionei o `step="0.1"` para incrementar da forma desejada.

Mudei um pouco a lógica, ao invés de verificar e alertar o usuário sempre que inserido um valor errado, eu optei por impossibilitar a adição de um valor fora do minimo permitido(*Vale lembrar que nenhuma validação no lado do cliente garante a segurança da informação, portanto valide no lado do servidor também*).

Enxuguei um pouco o `HTML` para ficar mais visual, veja se te atende:

```js
$(function(){  //Executa ao carregar
  valorMinimoCreabas(); //Chama a função que defini o minimo

  $("#creabas").on("change", function(){ //sempre que creabas for alterado
    $("#creabas2").val(""); //Limpo o campo creabas2
    valorMinimoCreabas();  //Redefino o minimo
  });
});

function valorMinimoCreabas(){
  var min = parseFloat($("#creabas").val())+0.3; //Somo 0.3 ao valor originar de creabas
  
  if(!isNaN(min))
    $("#creabas2").prop("min", min); //Defino minimo valor
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<label for="creabas">
   Creatinina (posterior à admissão hospitalar e a mais   próxima da randomização): 
   <span style="color:red;">*</span>
</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="00.00" value="2.3" step="0.1" name="creabas" id="creabas" min="0" max="15.0" />
   <span style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon"> mg/dL </span>
</div>
<div>
   <label>
      Se necessário, informe mais uma medida da creatinina nas 48 horas prévias a randomização, que comprove a elevação de 0,3mg/dL ou incremento de 50% no valor basal: 
      <span style="color:red;">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="00.00" name="creabas2" id="creabas2" min="0" max="15.0" step="0.1" width="100"/>
<span style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">
   mg/dl
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo, eu já consegui resolver e postei a solução, mais mesmo assim agredeço a sua ajuda!!

Comment: sem problemas, espero ter ajudado :}